# WPF DataGrid Insert and Update binding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a Collection. I want a user to be able to edit elements (insert and update), therefore he can edit the content of the cells.

What do I have to do to update the collection element, so it has the changes of the cell edit?

I used the `RowEditFinished` event, and thus I have access to the rows and columns of the `DataGrid`, but how can I find out, what is the content of the edited cell and which element it belongs to?

Comment: You are _describing_ your code. You need to _show_ us your code for use to be able to help you.

Comment: *how can I find out?* You can go to the [`DataGrid` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN, or search online for any of the hundreds of `DataGrid` tutorials like the rest of us.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implementing INotifyPropertyChanged :

If an object implementing INotifyPropertyChanged Interface it’ll raise a property changed event when its property changes.Here is an example demonstrates the data binding with both an object implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and also a normal DependencyProperty.

Create a class named Customer in the your project and implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
Define INotifyPropertyChanged Members,
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
   {
     PropertyChanged(this, e);
   }
}
```

In property setter invoke OnPropertyChanged by passing property name like,

```
private string _Name;

public string Name
{
  get
  {
     return _Name;
  }
  set
  {
    _Name = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
  }
}
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs add an ObservableCollection of customer object as Dependency
property inorder to make sure that UI is updating while we assigning that customer list
to another list or object.If we are making it as a normal property UI will update only if
we add new object to customerlist or any change occurs to the underlying properties.

```
public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerList
{
  get { return (ObservableCollection<Customer>)
GetValue(CustomerListProperty); }
  set { SetValue(CustomerListProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.
//This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...

public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomerListProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("CustomerList",
typeof(ObservableCollection<Customer>), typeof(MainPage),
    new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Customer>()));
```

I also added a DependencyProperty FirstName in MainPage.xaml.cs just to show the binding of a simple DependencyProperty.

```
public string FirstName
{
  get { return (string)GetValue(FirstNameProperty); }
  set { SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.
//This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...

public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstNameProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("FirstName", typeof(string), typeof(MainPage),
  new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```

In MainPage.XAML add a datagrid and textbox and bind it to the ObservableCollection and DependencyProperty respectively.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <DataGrid.Columns  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=TestUC,
                                    Path=CustomerList}">

                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />

                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Like">
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                        <Button Content="{Binding Like}" BorderThickness="0" />
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
<TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox"
Text="{Binding ElementName=TestUC, Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"
Width="100"
Height="25"
Margin="0,10,0,10" />
```

For Understanding PropertyChanged event, I added a button and just updating the customer object in the click event so that you can see the changes in the datagrid.When you change the property of Customer object from click event you can see that the UI is updating accordingly.

Comment: And then the Collection will be changed, too?
What do I have to do when I don't want to autogenerate columns, because I have like Button Columns and so on

Comment: added a sample code of custom datagrid "dgUsers", it allows you to add column with button and other column that you need